# No overload when using a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am getting a ContextSwitchDeadlock when I try to add a large amount of graphics to a map. I would love to use the BackgroundWorker Class especially since I have never had the opportunity, but I am not sure how to in this situation.

C#:

```
private void AttributeSearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(RunQuery);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

        }

        private void RunQuery(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _attributeQueryGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Clear();

            QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask("http://xx.x.x.xxx:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Calvert_City_Test/MapServer/2");
            queryTask.ExecuteCompleted += GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted;
            queryTask.Failed += GeneralQueryTask_Failed;

            var dirty = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Query query = new Query();
            query.OutFields.Add("*");
            query.ReturnGeometry = true;
            query.Where = "CIS_METR LIKE '%" + QueryParametersTextbox.Text + "%' OR COMMENTS LIKE '%" + QueryParametersTextbox.Text + "%'";
            query.OutSpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;               
            queryTask.ExecuteAsync(query);



        }

        // Draw results when query is complete
        private void GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.QueryEventArgs args)
        {
            // Clear previous results
            QueryDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["QueryResults"] as GraphicsLayer;
            graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();

            // Check for new results 

            FeatureSet featureSet = args.FeatureSet;
            bool isExceedTransferLimit = args.ExceededTransferLimit;

            try
            {
                if (featureSet.Features.Count > 0 && isExceedTransferLimit == false)
                {
                    // Add results to map
                    foreach (Graphic resultFeature in featureSet.Features)
                    {
                        //resultFeature.Symbol = ResultsFillSymbol;
                        graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(resultFeature);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No features found");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        // Notify when query fails
        private void GeneralQueryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Query failed: " + args.Error);
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ProgressTextbox.Content = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }
```

I know that the logic is off in this, but I am clueless on how to fix it. I have referred to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker(v=vs.95).aspx for help with how to use the class, however the information provided is not for this specific situation. 
What I am wanting to do:

When the user clicks the Search button, it will Run the query. This works perfectly. The problem is when it runs the GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted I get a ContextSwitchDeadlock message if there are a large amount of records. This also leaves the UI unresponsive.

From what I have read I would need to put:

```
if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    break;
}
```

where the time consuming task takes place. The problem is that there is no overloaded method for me to be able to do the QueryTask and the BackgroundWorker. Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: I am surprised it gets past QueryDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  You cannot access a UI element from a background thread.

Comment: If your `Completed` event is taking long time too, why not to put it in `do_work` too? You can invoke the UI from `do_work` too.

Comment: The completed event is the problem. The query runs fine.. I need the foreach loop in the completed to be a BackgroundWorker task.

Comment: I am pretty sure the whole thing needs to be reworked.. I am afraid that it is not even possible to use the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: your completed event is the dowork event.  Your event name is confusing, your code says: `bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted);`  So DoWork is your ExecuteCompleted...

Comment: But you don't have a completed event handler.  That is a DoWork event handler and you cannot access the UI from there.

Comment: I am going to update the code to what I had before. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I updated the code. I am not sure how to get the long process of the foreach loop into my Background Worker DoWork.

Comment: @JLott When you want to update UI control from another tread, you can use `MethodInvoker`. Read more here: [MethodInvoker Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @etaiso Looks like that could work, but I am still not sure how to implement that in this situation

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you get `ContextSwitchDeadlock`, what is the other issue you are trying to solve? Is the UI still freezing after making the changes with the `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: learn the ProducerConsumer pattern.

Comment: @etaiso The UI freezes when the ExecuteComplete is running, even though it is ExecuteAsync